# google maps API geocoding get address components

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working with [google map API(geocoding)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) and I noticed the following. If I print the array for "x" address, it prints an array of objects of size 9. where the country is in the index 6. If I enter some other "y" address, sometimes the array of objects is less than 9 and the index to get the country is not 6 anymore. I have tried with different addresses as some of them have the size consistent as 9 some of them at 6 some of them 7 and so on. Is there a set way for me to access the country without having to check the size of the array and avoid this issue?

my code

```
     let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
     this.addressArray = place.address_components;
     if(this.addressArray.length === 9) {
        this.country = this.addressArray[6].short_name;
        this.zipcode = this.addressArray[7].short_name;
     } else {
        this.country = this.addressArray[5].short_name;
        this.zipcode = this.addressArray[6].short_name;
     }
```

I figured I can use `place.formatted_address` and access the last word which is always the country, but for zipcode and some other information on the address the order is not always the same.
Below is an example of the structure of the array of objects I'm printing.

I thought about filtering the array to find the index of types that contains the word country,zipcode, etc and based on the index returned get the country or whatever I want to retrieve. I wonder if there's an easier way to accomplish this straight from the google API geocode.

This question [How to get country from google maps api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41077830/how-to-get-country-from-google-maps-api) talks about someone entering the address. My application uses google autocomplete. I thought the API was smarter to handle the missing data of people not entering a complete address. Also, the answer address in that question is part of my explanation of my question of me saying I knew I could filter the array

[image]

Comment: There's no other way. As you can see it's an array of results. Nothing more.

Comment: @MrUpsidown good comment. I needed a it's not possible or it's possible. Thanks! I thought I was maybe using the api wrong

Comment: @xomena That question is referencing when user types the address. Mine does the autocomplete. I thought when it does the autocomplete google will handle everything and have all the data needed. As I mentioned in my question I knew about filtering the array and all that but I wish the API was smarter

Comment: In address components you will get only things that are used in formatter template. Different areas even withing the same country have different templates that means you will have different set of address components and you cannot get all of them. There is no strict order so you have to analyze types of address components.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

related question: [Wrong country code returned by Google Geocoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735051/wrong-country-code-returned-by-google-geocoder)

You need to parse through the address_components array's types, looking for the entry with a type of country.

```
var country = '';
for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < place.address_components[i].types.length; j++) {
    if (place.address_components[i].types[j] == "country") {
      country = place.address_components[i];
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = country.long_name +" (" + country.short_name +")";
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/3f5dt7zx/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -33.8688,
      lng: 151.2195
    },
    zoom: 13
  });
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
  infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
  });

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
      // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
      window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17); // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);
    var country = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < place.address_components[i].types.length; j++) {
        if (place.address_components[i].types[j] == "country") {
          country = place.address_components[i];
        }
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = country.long_name + " (" + country.short_name + ")";
    infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
    infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
    infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = country.long_name;
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#description {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#infowindow-content .title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#infowindow-content {
  display: none;
}

#map #infowindow-content {
  display: inline;
}

.pac-card {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#pac-container {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.pac-controls {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 11px;
}

.pac-controls label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#title {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pac-card" id="pac-card">
  <div>
    <div id="type-selector" class="pac-controls">
    </div>
    <div id="pac-container">
      <input id="pac-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="country"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
  <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
  <span id="place-name" class="title"></span><br>
  <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" async defer></script>
```