# Geopy Google v3 - Extracting address components from location.raw

Tags: python, nested-lists, geopy

I have this python script where I get a list of addresses from a SQL table and then pass them to googles api using Geopy to get them Geocoded then write the data back to a different SQL table.

I'm currently stuck trying to extract out the address parts from address_components.

I've tried quite a few things like converting `location.raw` to Json, using other address parsers (but i'm not in the US) and my python is not strong. I also can't just reference the list part directly as different addresses will have different lengths so when I apply it to the dataframe later it fails as the lists arent all the same length. eg `loc_raw0.append(location.raw['address_components'][0]['long_name'])`

I'm currently trying to use a nested For loop just to get the street number out and then will replicate fo the other parts.

Whats happening is `k` will equal `'address_components'` however `v` will equal `'{'long_name': '46', 'short_name': '46', 'types': ['street_number']}'`  and not just `'street_number'`.

```
        for k, v in location.raw.items():
            if k == 'address_components' and 'street_number' in v:
                loc_street_number.append(location.raw['long_name'])
                print(loc_street_number)
```

[pic of list v contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwzU1.png)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query, columns=['address'])


loc_Inputaddress = []
loc_Longitude = []
loc_Latitude = []
loc_Matchedaddress = []

loc_subpremise = []
loc_street_number = []
loc_road = []
loc_locality = []
loc_AdminArea1 = []
loc_AdminArea2 = []
loc_postcode = []
loc_type = []


for address in df.address:
    try:
        inputAddress = address
        location = g.geocode(inputAddress, timeout=15)

        loc_Inputaddress.append(inputAddress)
        loc_Longitude.append(location.longitude)
        loc_Latitude.append(location.latitude)
        loc_Matchedaddress.append(location.address)
        loc_type.append(location.raw['types'][0])

        #get address type
        print(loc_type.append(location.raw['types'][0]))

        #print(location.raw['address_components'])

  
        for k, v in location.raw.items():
            if k == 'address_components' and 'street_number' in v:
                loc_street_number.append(location.raw['long_name'])
                print(loc_street_number)

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error, skipping address...', e)
```

Comment: Remember that it is not recommended to post images of data. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `v` is a list of dictionaries and, as far as I understand, you want the `long_name` of the dictionary that has a `street_number` type. This example should help you:

```python
v = [{
    "long_name": "40",
    "short_name": "40",
    "types": ["subpremise"]
},
{
    "long_name": "46",
    "short_name": "46",
    "types": ["street_number"]
},
{
    "long_name": "Aongatete",
    "short_name": "Aongatete",
    "types": ["locality", "political"]
}]

# Iterate over v because it is a list
for address_component in v:
    # Check if one of the address component types is "street_number"
    if "street_number" in address_component["types"]:
        print(address_component["long_name"])
        break

# Output:
# 46
```

[Demo in myCompiler](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/CRe0Jgt)

Comment: Thank you so much, its all working. Ive spent 1.5 days on this trying different things but I can finally get this data out!

Comment: in some instances an address might not have an street number for example - do you have any tips on keeping the arrays the same length if there is no data to add?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function written to extract the address components based on the js example by [geocodezip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210329/geocodezip) found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50236084/12945884) :

```
def extract_address_details(address_components):
    """
    extract_address_details extracts address parts from the details of the google maps api response

    :param address_components: a dict representing the details['address_components'] response from the google maps api
    :return: a dict of the address components
    """
    # set up the loop parameters for each component
    count = len(address_components)
    looplist = range(0, count)

    #loop through the indices of the address components
    for i in looplist:

        #set up the loop parameters for the component types
        tcount = len(address_components[i]['types'])
        tlooplist = range(0, tcount)
        
        #loop through the indices of the address component types
        for t in tlooplist:

            #match the type, pull the short_name from the appropriate component as a string
            match address_components[i]['types'][t]:
                case "subpremise":
                    subpremise = str(address_components[i]['short_name'])
                case "street_number":
                    street_number = str(address_components[i]['short_name'])
                case "route":
                    route = str(address_components[i]['short_name'])
                case "locality":
                    city = str(address_components[i]['short_name'])
                case "administrative_area_level_1":
                    state = str(address_components[i]['short_name'])
                case "postal_code":
                    postal_code = str(address_components[i]['short_name'])

    #assemble the street address
    address1 = street_number + " " + route + " " + subpremise

    #populate the return values
    data = {
        'address1': address1,
        'city': city,
        'state': state,
        'postal_code': postal_code
    }
    
    return data
```